# Craftsman Leaf Blower wont start, ignition coil failure?

Tags: sparkplugs, ignition-coil, two-stroke

In a previous question I asked about repairing a carb for my leaf blower and the repair didnt hold so I bought a new one. Replaced fuel filter and fuel lines, also replaced the carb gasket.

I seem to get fuel into the primer bulb ok. I keep pulling the engine and it wont start at all. I open the crank case plug and fuel mix collected in the crank case comes out. Also I can feel air getting sucked into the engine on the first stroke so it feels like compression is there and fuel is making it in.

Got to the flywheel and the magnets are clean. I grounded the spark plug to the engine body and saw a very tiny weak occasional spark. The spark plug was dirty so I replaced it and saw the same thing.

I tested the ignition coil with a multimeter and got a reading of 4.6 on the 20k ohms setting. Most two stroke repair  guides suggest a reading between 2 and 5 is normal. I figured it might be bad so i ordered a used one for my model and tested that and got the exact same reading.

Just for sanity I shot some starting fluid into the carb and its still not firing.

Is it possible I got two bad ignition coils here or is this maybe not a spark issue at all? I am pretty sure air and fuel are getting sucked in and even if they arent then it should have ignited the starting fluid.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the kill switch was shorted on the new ignition coil. I used the switch from the old coil and the new coil and it runs great now!